# Rotating SVG with CSS from bottom of group

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying create some kind of gauge animation. I added two simple gauges  inside a rectangel . When I try to rotate a needle it doesn't rotate around its bottom part. Instead it rotates around another point even though I state to rotate around bottom center. What should I do to rotate the needle from bottom? Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the animation I am trying to achieve

[image: Gaugae Animation]

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
    #Gaugaetip2 {
      animation: dance 2s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes dance {
      100% {
      transform-origin: bottom center;
      transform:  rotate(-25deg);
      }
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <svg width="135px" height="135px" viewBox="0 0 135 135" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>test</title>
        <defs>
            <path d="M17.6298701,13.9630295 L17.6298701,4.43831169 L15.6298701,4.43831169 L15.6298701,13.9630295 C14.6733943,14.3565661 14,15.2976952 14,16.3961039 C14,17.8485411 15.177433,19.025974 16.6298701,19.025974 C18.0823073,19.025974 19.2597403,17.8485411 19.2597403,16.3961039 C19.2597403,15.2976952 18.5863459,14.3565661 17.6298701,13.9630295 L17.6298701,13.9630295 Z" id="path-1"></path>
            <path d="M18.91403,13.9099151 L18.91403,4.38519729 L16.91403,4.38519729 L16.91403,13.9099151 C15.9575542,14.3034517 15.2841598,15.2445808 15.2841598,16.3429895 C15.2841598,17.7954267 16.4615928,18.9728596 17.91403,18.9728596 C19.3664671,18.9728596 20.5439001,17.7954267 20.5439001,16.3429895 C20.5439001,15.2445808 19.8705058,14.3034517 18.91403,13.9099151 L18.91403,13.9099151 Z" id="path-3"></path>
        </defs>
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="test" transform="translate(-30.000000, -30.000000)">
                <g transform="translate(30.000000, 30.000000)">
                    <rect id="background" fill="#4BBCE9" x="0" y="0" width="135" height="135" rx="8"></rect>
                    <g id="Gauge" transform="translate(5.136364, 8.642857)">
                        <g id="Group-3" transform="translate(0.149351, 0.383117)">
                            <ellipse id="Oval-3" stroke="#D8D8D8" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="16.6298701" cy="16.3961039" rx="15.7792208" ry="15.7792208"></ellipse>
                            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            </mask>
                            <use id="Gaugaetip2" fill="#D8D8D8" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Gauge-Copy-3" transform="translate(95.551948, 9.642857)">
                        <ellipse id="Oval-3" stroke="#D8D8D8" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="15.7792208" cy="15.7792208" rx="15.7792208" ry="15.7792208"></ellipse>
                        <mask id="mask-4" fill="white">
                            <use xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                        </mask>
                        <use id="Gaugetip" fill="#D8D8D8" transform="translate(17.914030, 11.679028) rotate(25.000000) translate(-17.914030, -11.679028) " xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `transform-origin` to the element itself. As this is a fixed property that does not change over time, it shouldn't be part of the keyframes.

```
#Gaugaetip2 {
  animation: dance 2s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: center 84%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
@keyframes dance {
  100% {
  transform:  rotate(-25deg);
  }
}
```

I also adjusted the origin position a little to stay centered on the round part.

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/dowm6eff/

Comment: I added your suggestions but still needle doesn't rotate from its bottom.I am trying to rotate the needle inside the circle. Needle should rotate inside the center of circle

Comment: Edited to add the `transform-box: fill-box` to make the transform-origin work properly on all browsers.

Comment: Btw, since your code uses percentages, if browser is resized, animation doesn't happen around center. Is there a way to always animate around the center of the circle ? Firefox works but safari has above bug.

Comment: About the resizing, it should still work fine. Look at this updated example (try to resize the result area): https://jsfiddle.net/dowm6eff/1/

Comment: It fails on Safari. Open that page in Safari and try to decrease or increase web page size with Command +